# Rename a bunch of files: switch running number

Tags: perl, rename

I would like to rename some thousands of files with the name structure: 
`IMAGE_6290.JPG` up to `IMAGE_9999.JPG`

into: 
`image_0001.JPG` up to `image_3710.JPG`

So basically there should be a shift by `6289`

I have tried the rename command (under Debian 7.0) but I don't know how to subtract two variables.

My best try is :

```
rename -n 's/(\d{4})\.JPG$/_$1-6289\.JPG/' *.JPG
```

but it gives results like: 
`IMAGE6484.JPG` renamed as `IMAGE_6484-6289.JPG`

Any help?

Many thanks!

Comment: is there or isn't there a _ in the original names?

Answer (score 2):

```
rename -n 's/(\d{4})\.JPG$/sprintf("_%04d.JPG",$1-6289)/e' *.JPG
```

Comment: If there should be leading zeros, then the following would do that, `s/(\d{4})\.JPG$/sprintf "_%04d", ($1-6289) . ".JPG"/e` Also, is it necessary to escape the period before `JPEG`?

Comment: Do you know some solid documentation so I can get more familiar to perl?

Comment: The documentation is at http://perldoc.perl.org.  You may want to read through http://www.perl.org/books/beginning-perl

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to do that in command line, but in Perl (since you have the [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) tag), you can extract variables using the
[baby cart](http://search.cpan.org/~book/perlsecret-1.004/lib/perlsecret.pod) operator.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @jpg_files = glob "*.JPG";

foreach my $file (@jpg_files){
    if (my $new_name = $file =~ s/(\d{4}).JPG/_@{[$1 - 6289]}.JPG/r) {
        rename $file, $new_name;
    }

    # or simply
    rename $file , $file =~ s/(\d{4}).JPG/_@{[$1 - 6289]}.JPG/r;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it from the command line. But I will copy your script and use it for the next batch processing task. Many thanks!